# How to add values of iterations in Java

Tags: java

I am attempting to write a script that has an iteration of points possible and points earned for each number of assignments submitted.

I then want to create a variable for total points possible and total points earned to be able to create a progress report that presents these numbers.

Here is the code and everything works except that my math is wrong on the total possible and the total earned.

```
String anotherCourse = "yes"; // variable to control running program
                                    // again
    do {
        String studentName = ""; // Student Name
        String courseName = ""; // Course Name
        int assignSub = 0; // Number of Assignments submitted
        double pointsWorth = 0; // Points worth for each assignment
        double pointsEarned = 0; // Points earned for each assignment

        // Calculated

        double currentPercent = 0; // Current Percentage
        String letterGrade = ""; // Letter Grade

        // Display header
        System.out.println("\t\t---------------------------");
        System.out.println("\t\t   What's Your Grade???");
        System.out.println("\t\t---------------------------");

        // Ask for student name and course name
        System.out.print("Enter student name: ");
        studentName = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter course name: ");
        courseName = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println();

        // Ask how many assignments were taken
        System.out.print("How many assignments have you submitted: ");
        assignSub = input.nextInt();

        while (assignSub < 0) {
            System.out
                    .println("Assignments submitted point value must be greater than 0...Try Again!");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.print("How many assignments have you submitted: ");
            assignSub = input.nextInt();
        }
        // and error code if is <= to 0 they take in again

        int totalEarned = 0;
        int totalWorth = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= assignSub; i++) {

            // How many points is the assignment worth?
            System.out.println();
            System.out.print("How many points was assignment " + i
                    + " worth: ");
            pointsWorth = input.nextDouble();

            while (pointsWorth < 0) { // Error Message
                System.out
                        .println("Assignment point value must be greater than 0...Try Again!");
                System.out.println();
                System.out.print("How many points was assignment " + i
                        + " worth: ");
                pointsWorth = input.nextDouble();
            } // end while

            System.out.print("How many points did you score: ");
            pointsEarned = input.nextDouble();
            if (pointsEarned >0 && pointsEarned < pointsWorth){

            }
            else  { //Error Message
                System.out.println("Points scored must be between assignment worth and greater than or equal to 0...Try Again!");
                System.out.println();
                System.out.print("How many points did you score: ");
                pointsEarned = input.nextDouble();
            }// end while

            totalEarned = (int) (pointsEarned + i);
            totalWorth = (int) (pointsWorth + i);



        }// end for

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("\tProgress Report for " + studentName);
        System.out.println("\tCourse Name is " + courseName);
        System.out
                .println("--------------------------------------------------");

        System.out
                .println("Number of assignments submitted....." + assignSub);
        System.out.println("Total points possible..............."
                + totalWorth);
        System.out.println("Total points earned................."
                + totalEarned);

        // calculate the current percentage

        currentPercent = (totalEarned / totalWorth) * 100;
        System.out.println("Total percent to date...............%.2f%%\n"
                + currentPercent);

        // Write a nested if else statement to figure out letter grade based
        // on standard grade chart

        if (currentPercent <= 100 && currentPercent >= 93)
            letterGrade = "A";
        else if (currentPercent < 93 && currentPercent >= 90)
            letterGrade = "A-";
        else if (currentPercent < 90 && currentPercent >= 87)
            letterGrade = "B+";
        else if (currentPercent < 87 && currentPercent >= 83)
            letterGrade = "B";
        else if (currentPercent < 83 && currentPercent >= 80)
            letterGrade = "B-";
        else if (currentPercent < 80 && currentPercent >= 77)
            letterGrade = "C+";
        else if (currentPercent < 77 && currentPercent >= 73)
            letterGrade = "C";
        else if (currentPercent < 73 && currentPercent >= 70)
            letterGrade = "C-";
        else if (currentPercent < 70 && currentPercent >= 67)
            letterGrade = "D+";
        else if (currentPercent < 67 && currentPercent >= 63)
            letterGrade = "D";
        else if (currentPercent < 63 && currentPercent >= 60)
            letterGrade = "D-";
        else
            letterGrade = "E";

        System.out.println("Letter grade to date.................."
                + letterGrade);

        System.out.println();
        System.out
                .print("--------------------------------------------------");



        // This code ends the do while to run entire program again
        System.out
                .println("Enter yes if there is another class you want to calculate: ");
        anotherCourse = input.next();
        input.nextLine(); // causes skipping issue to fix
        System.out.print("\n\n\n");
    } while (anotherCourse.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"));
    System.out
            .print("-----------------------------------------------------");
} // end of main
```

Comment: Then fix your math.  What's your question?  And if everything except for one small part works, why include a hundred lines of noisy code that hides your actual problem?

Comment: Check your loop, have you?

Comment: Please do not paste the entire code. No one is going to go through it. Better you paste only the part your code which has problem or where you need help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is where your `MATH` supposedly goes wrong.

```
totalEarned = (int) (pointsEarned + i);
totalWorth = (int) (pointsWorth + i);
```

Change the above code snippet to this:-

```
totalEarned = totalEarned + (int)pointsEarned;
totalWorth = totalWorth + (int)pointsWorth;
```

The first block is resetting the values of `totalEarned` & `totalWorth` for every iteration, whereas you need to aggregate that in your case.

Answer (score 0):

also, there is no need to check for the upper bound again in an else-if loop.

```
   if (currentPercent >= 93)
        letterGrade = "A";
    else if (currentPercent >= 90)
        letterGrade = "A-";
    else if (currentPercent >= 87)
        letterGrade = "B+";
    else if (currentPercent >= 83)
        letterGrade = "B";
    else if (currentPercent >= 80)
        letterGrade = "B-";
    else if (currentPercent >= 77)
        letterGrade = "C+";
    else if (currentPercent >= 73)
        letterGrade = "C";
    else if (currentPercent >= 70)
        letterGrade = "C-";
    else if (currentPercent >= 67)
        letterGrade = "D+";
    else if (currentPercent >= 63)
        letterGrade = "D";
    else if (currentPercent >= 60)
        letterGrade = "D-";
    else
        letterGrade = "E";
```